# How does the Higgs field decelerate particles that travel at the speed of light?

Tags: particle-physics, higgs, interactions

The Higgs mechanism is supposed to give mass to most particles in the standard model. The Higgs field has a positive VEV. The Mexican Hat potential is the visible expression. When the field is zero, the energy of the vacuum has a local maximum, i.e., the top of the hat. At the rim, there is a field with zero energy, and this energy is achieved for all states on it (degeneracy). If the symmetry of the field breaks, after going from high to lower energies (or small to larger distances) the symmetry of the field is broken and perturbative calculations are performed around a point on the rim, spontaneously chosen.

So there is a non-zero Higgs field with minimum energy (the strange thing is that the energy has a local max for zero field). This doesn't mean there are real Higgs particles though. The particle field is the vacuum field of the Higgs and excitations around the rim form particles. It's a different vacuum though than that of "normal" particles. A false vacuum. The field doesn’t interact with particles like gauge fields (say the photon or gluon) mediate between particles. The field doesn’t act in between but directly on the supposed massless particles. But how does it decelerate these particles? It doesn't work like the marble that decelerates in honey. Is it like a photon decelerating in a medium? In this case the speed of the photon stays constant, while the marble halts. Is there literally a pull on massless particles? The three massless W and Z bosons gain mass after the symmetry break.

I know it's the math that gives the answer (U(1) symmetry break, Higgs doublets, Goldstone modes on the rim, etc.) but I heard it said once that if you can't explain what the math describes than you don't understand the physics. Especially the fact that if the field is zero the energy is maximal is confusing. Isn't this just a construction to fit the fact?

Anyhow, my main concern is the nature of the interaction. Not one like gauge fields but what then? Personally I prefer mass generation by bound massless particles, which is easier to imagine.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's think about why the Higgs field gives particles mass.

What is mass? Relativistically, mass is energy that a particle has when its kinetic energy goes to zero.

Consider a field called $\psi$, which could represent the pion, for example. The energy (technically energy density) of this field is
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} \dot\psi^2 - \frac{1}{2} (\nabla \psi)^2 + \frac{1}{2} m^2 \psi^2
\end{equation}
The first term is the kinetic energy, and the second term is the gradient energy. When we look in the limit when the kinetic and gradient energy goes to zero, we see the energy is dominated by the mass, as we expect.

When we include the Higgs field, the energy is modified to include the term
\begin{equation}
y \psi H \psi
\end{equation}
where $y$ is a constant (a *Yukawa* coupling).

In the standard model, we write $H = \bar{H} + h$, where $\bar{H}$ is the *vacuum expectation value* of the field. This is the value that the Higgs field takes in the vacuum, when there are no particles.

Because of this, the interaction energy becomes
\begin{equation}
y\bar{H} \psi^2 = \frac{1}{2} m^2 \psi^2
\end{equation}
where $m^2 = 2 y \bar{H}$.

**The interaction with the Higgs means there is some energy when the kinetic and gradient energy go to zero.** We interpret this energy as mass.

Second, why does a particle with mass travel at less than the speed of light? There are many questions that address this. One reason is that it costs an infinite amount of energy for a massive particle to travel at $c$.

Comment: *This is the value that the Higgs field takes in the vacuum, when there are no particles.*  Do you mean the rim of the hat? What I dont understand is how the zero field of the Higgs has higher energy (top of the hat) than the minimum, zero value on one of degenerate states on the rim. At small distances, the Higgs field is zero, and the energy a local max. Which of the two is considered the vacuum? The zero energy brim (with non-zero field), or the zero field at the origin (with non-zero energy). The VEV refers to the field or to the non-zero energy of the zero field ot the origin?

Comment: @Felicia The vacuum refers to the state at low energies / long distances, where we live in. (After all, we are much bigger than fundamental particles). The value of the field $\bar{H}$ which minimizes the energy is non-zero, and corresponds to the rim of the hat. This is crucial for the Higgs mechanism. There's nothing mysterious about a nonzero Higgs value having a smaller energy than a zero value. If you put a pencil on its tip, it will fall over. If we set the origin at the pencil tip, then the pencil has a lower energy when its center of mass has a nonzero value instead of a zero value.

Comment: What seems mysterious though, is the cause of the high central maximum (top of the hat). The pencil has a higher potential because its COM lies higher in the g field. But why the Higgs field has a local maximum energy at the center, where the field is zero? And shouldn't the zero field at the origin be considered the vacuum (because no field is present)?

Comment: @Felicia The vacuum is the state of lowest energy. The lowest energy state has a nonzero value of $\bar{H}$. There is absolutely no reason why $\bar{H}=0$ should have a lower energy. Indeed, if you think of the Mexican hat, it's clear that $\bar{H}=0$ (the top of the hat) has a higher energy than the rim of the hat.

Comment: But what is the *reason* it has a higher energy for a zero field? The reason a pencil balancing on a point is the gravity field and that's the cause of the break as well. But what causes the higher energy of the Higgs field when it's zero?

Comment: @Felicia The Higgs field has a potential energy, which is larger when the field is zero, than when the Higgs field is non-zero. It's exactly analogous to how there's a gravitational potential energy which means the pencil has larger energy when its center of mass is higher than when it is lower. Maybe you want to know *why* the Higgs field has a potential energy. That's not a question we can really answer. Our hypothesis is that the Higgs field has a potential energy of this form, and we compute the observable consequences of this, and we find they agree with experiment.

Comment: "Maybe you want to know why the Higgs field has a potential energy." Exactly! The pencil due to the g field it's in. But the Higgs field? It's just stated it has energy for zero field. But potential energy is defined in an external field. And also, how can a zero field, no particles that is, have an energy in the first place?

Comment: By the way, is there a "derivative energy" (like for the pion) for the Higgs field? If you take the angular derivative on the rim? That corresponds to a Goldstone boson. There is no energy needed in that direction. Does the derivative correspond to momentum (momentum operator)?

Comment: @Felicia The potential energy is not an external field. It is due to self interactions of the Higgs with itself. The potential energy has the form $V(H)=-\frac{\mu^2}{2} H^2 + \frac{\lambda}{4!} H^4$. There's no deep reason why the potential has this form, except that there's no reason for the Higgs *not* to have a potential/self interactions; we postulate that the Higgs has this potential, and the consequences agree with experiment. The Higgs field has *spatial derivative* energy (if it varies in real space), but there is no energy cost for "angular fluctuations" in "Higgs space."

Comment: The Higgs couples to itself. Its the source of the potential energy? Like the potential energy electrons get when couoling to themselves in an electron gas? One last question. How can the field have maximum energy if there are no particles (zero field)? What you mean that the field varies in real space?

Comment: This still doesn't answer *how* the Higgs field decelerates massless particles.

Comment: @Felicia The Higgs field gives particles mass. Particles with mass must travel below the speed of light. That's kind of all there is to say. If you are looking for a "classical" model which better fits with your intuition of how the world works, like particles moving through molasses, unfortunately there's no model that's accurate and adds any information. This video by Feynman about "why" questions is very relevant here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36GT2zI8lVA

Comment: Yes, I know particles with mass travel slower than light. And I understand that the math fits. But I don't see *how* the field gives mass. Does it pull on particles, like photons?

Comment: @Felicia There's energy associated with the interaction between the higgs and, say, an electron. When the Higgs takes on a vacuum expectation value, this energy is quadratic in the electron field. It is energy that a free electron has as its kinetic energy goes to zero. This looks like mass from the point of view of experiments we can do with electrons.

Comment: @Felicia I feel I've said all there is to say. If you are unsatisfied, all I can say is that I sympathize that it is difficult to grapple with these abstract concepts. But, at least at our current level of understanding, there are no hidden cogs or wheels underneath that you are missing that will give a more "mechanical" or "intuitive" picture of what's going on, People that claim to be able to give you such a picture are giving you an inaccurate analogy, at best. This is just how Nature is, as far as anyone can tell.

Comment: Well, I think that's exactly the reason why nature is not like described by the Higgs. I think there is just a deeper level of particles.

Comment: Is that (about) 240 GeV VEV the value at the top of the Mexican hat potential?

Comment: @Felicia I thought of something that perhaps should be clarified. The electroweak phase transition (where the Higgs goes from the top to the bottom of the Mexican hat potential) is a catastrophic event, where the state of the vacuum changes, and therefore particle physics changes. It is not that a massless electron travels along, the Higgs transitions, and suddenly the electron is massive. It is more like, particles that existed before the transition, cease to exist, and a new set of particles (excitations of the new vacuum state) exist after.